# Total row count in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I totally understand the `count(*) from table where partitionId = 'test'` will return the count of the rows. I could see that it takes the same time as `select * from table where partitionId = 'test`.

Is there any other alternative in Cassandra to retrieve the count of the rows in an efficient way?

Comment: Is the count required per partition key level or table level?

Comment: @dilsingi  It is per partition.

Comment: Unless you want to maintain a separate “counter” table to get the counts, select count(*) is your best bet, hoping partitions are small. As partitions grow big or table level count is simply going to timeout

Answer (score 2):

You can compare results of `select *` & `select count(*)` if you run cqlsh, and enable tracing there with `tracing on` command - it will print time that is required for execution of corresponding command. The difference between both queries is only in what amount of data should be returned back.

But anyway, to find number of rows Cassandra needs to hit SSTable(s), and scan entries - performance could be different if you have partition spread between multiple SSTables - this may depend on your compaction strategy for tables, that is selected based on your reading/writing patterns.

Comment: I am looking for the best way to get the count :( Still I didnt get anything and I am ending up in select count (*)

Answer (score 0):

As Alex Ott mentioned, the `COUNT(*)` needs to go through the entire partition to know that total.

The fact is that Cassandra wants to avoid locks and as a result they do not maintain a number of row in their sstables and each time you do an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE`, you may actually *overwrite* another entry which is just marked as a *tombstone* (i.e. it's not an in place overwrite, instead it saves the new data at the end of the sstable and marks the old data as *dead*).

The `COUNT(*)` will go through the sstables and count all the entries not marked as a *tombstone*. That's very costly. We're used to SQL having the total number of rows in a table or an index so `COUNT(*)` on those is instantaneous... not here.

One solution I've used is to have Elasticsearch installed on your Cassandra cluster. One of the parameters Elasticsearch saves in their stats is the number of rows in a table. I don't remember the exact query, but more or less you can just a `count` request and you get a result in like 100ms, always, whatever the number is. Even in the 10s of millions of rows. Just like with a `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` the result will always be an approximation if you have many writes happening in parallel. It will stabilize if the writes stop for *long enough* (possibly about 1 or 2 seconds).